# How to calculate filter coefficients for a polyphase filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, signal-processing, linear-interpolation

I want to know the procedure to calculate filter coefficients for a polyphase digital filter. I want to interpolate image by factor 2 strictly in 1D. I have read some articles about polyphase digital filter working principle. My understanding about calculating filter coefficients is.. I need to know number of phases, taps and filter type for a polyphase digital filter, is this right?.

But I really don't understand on what factors the number of phases depends on, and how to calculate coefficients. It would be really helpful if someone can explain me.. I want to start with bilinear polyphase digital filter and then try bicubic.

Comment: Polyphase filters are used for resampling by *non-integer* factors.  If you're upsampling by a factor of 2, then you don't need a polyphase filter.  You just need a plain ol' low-pass filter.

Comment: thanks Matt , actually i am upsampling [4:2:2 to 4:4:4] chroma values...problem is ..when i upsample image having saturated colours, i could find artifacts in edges of saturated colours.. so want to make upsampling luma adaptive ..for this i need a polypase filter, so that filter switches to different phase on certain luma conditions..

Comment: Ah, you should maybe write a question about your specific use case, since  it's pretty interesting, but not at all like what you asked for.  I can only guess at the best way to do luma-adaptive 4:2:2 -> 4:4:4.

Comment: @MattTimmermans is totally incorrect—people (including me) use polyphase implementations of interpolators by integer factors, and decimators by integer factors. It is only the combination of the two that gives non-integer rational-rate resamplers. The bottom of page 8 shows here shows polyphase interpolation, and page 9 shows decimation: http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~schniter/ee700/handouts/multirate.pdf

Comment: However, @MattTimmermans is right that polyphase filters in general do resampling, and most references (like the PDF I linked to previously) describe only this application. Your specific application sounds like it might have an efficient polyphase implementation—did you read about it in a paper somewhere? I suspect only a tiny subset of people who can make a polyphase resampler would know how to use that technique for adaptive filtering.

Comment: Oops, yes.  @AhmedFasih is correct, and polyphase is useful for resampling by (especially large) integer factors too.